# Why can't you call object attributes within __init__?

Tags: python, constructor, wxpython

I'm trying to understand why you can call an object's attribute within a class' method, but not within it's constructor. For example:

```
class Panel1(wx.Panel):

    #include Frame in the constructor
    def __init__(self, parent, frame):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        #set up so objects assigned in Frame (and it's children) can be called
        self.frame = frame
        button = wx.Button(self, label='Test')
        #button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda event: self.onButton(event))
        button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onButton)

        pprint(vars(self.frame))


    def onButton(self, event):
        print("Button pressed.")
        pprint(vars(self.frame))
        #the following fails in the constructor as panel2 for some reason is not callable
        a = self.frame.panel2.a
        print("123: " + str(a))
```

Could someone point me to a link that explains why this isn't possible in the constructor?

Thanks!

*****EDIT****

Below is functional code to help explain my question better. If you try to call Panel2 attributes via the parent within Panel1's constructor, it fails. But it works fine when done inside Panel1's onButton method. I'd like to understand why.

```
import wx
from pprint import pprint

class Panel1(wx.Panel):

    #include Frame in the constructor
    def __init__(self, parent, frame):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        self.frame = frame
        self.strPanel1 = "Panel1 string"
        self.intPanel1 = 0

        button = wx.Button(self, label='Test')
        button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onButton)

        self.textbox = wx.TextCtrl(self)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        sizer.Add(self.textbox, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        sizer.Add(button, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        #pprint self.frame attributes fail here

    def onButton(self, event):
        #but not here!?!
        print("Panel1 button pressed.")
        pprint(vars(self.frame))
        Panel2str = self.frame.panel2.strPanel2
        print(Panel2str)
        Panel2int = self.frame.panel2.intPanel2
        print(str(Panel2int))
        #Panel2 button press counter
        self.frame.panel2.intPanel2 += 1
        self.frame.panel2.trigger()

    def trigger(self):
        print("Panel1 has been triggered")

class Panel2(wx.Panel):

    #include Frame in the constructor
    def __init__(self, parent, frame):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        self.frame = frame
        self.strPanel2 = "Panel2 string"
        self.intPanel2 = 0

        button = wx.Button(self, label='Test')
        button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onButton)

        self.textbox = wx.TextCtrl(self)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        sizer.Add(self.textbox, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        sizer.Add(button, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        #pprint self.frame attributes fail here

    def onButton(self, event):
        #but not here!?!
        print("Panel2 button pressed.")
        pprint(vars(self.frame))
        Panel1str = self.frame.panel1.strPanel1
        print(Panel1str)
        Panel1int = self.frame.panel1.intPanel1
        print(str(Panel1int))
        #Panel1 button press counter
        self.frame.panel1.intPanel1 += 1
        self.frame.panel1.trigger()

    def trigger(self):
        print("Panel2 has been triggered")

class Frame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="My Frame")

        #Spliiting the frame
        splitter = wx.SplitterWindow(self)

        #Send frame to children
        self.panel1 = Panel1(splitter, self)
        self.panel2 = Panel2(splitter, self) 

        splitter.SplitVertically(self.panel1, self.panel2, 0)
        splitter.SetMinimumPaneSize(200)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(splitter, 1, wx.EXPAND)

        self.SetSizer(sizer)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = Frame()
    frame.Show()
    frame.Centre()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: What exactly is `frame` and `panel2`? The comments says `panel2 is not callable`, why do you think it has anything to do with your `Panel1` constructor? I mean, the `frame` is given as an argument to that constructor, and `panel2` is a property of that argument meaning your issue is unrelated to your class. Please elaborate, with more code and information as for now it makes no sense.

Comment: Always share the entire error message. Variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. The answer to the question in the title is that you can, of course.

Comment: Can you please provide a *minimal* example of what you don't understand? Your description implies a class with an initialiser and about one or two attributes should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

> Below is functional code to help explain my question better. If you try to call Panel2 attributes via the parent within Panel1's constructor, it fails.

It fails, because at the time your `Panel1.__init__` is called, `frame.panel2` is not set yet. Look at your `Frame` class:

```
class Frame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="My Frame")

        #Spliiting the frame
        splitter = wx.SplitterWindow(self)

        #Send frame to children
        self.panel1 = Panel1(splitter, self)
        self.panel2 = Panel2(splitter, self)

        ...
```

When your `Panel1` is initialized, `panel2` is not set yet. It will only be set once `Panel1` is done initializing and has been assigned to `frame.panel1`. If you absolutely need to access `panel2` into `Panel1.__init__`, then you could make it so that your `Panel1` take care of it. For example:

```
class Panel1:
    def __init__(self, frame):
        # Initialize panel2 and assign it to our frame
        frame.panel2 = Panel2(frame)

        # Now we can do whatever with panel2
        frame.panel2

class Panel2:
    def __init__(self, frame):
        pass

class Frame:
    def __init__(self):
        # This initialize panel1, and internally initialize panel2
        self.panel1 = Panel1(self)


frame = Frame()
```